# tensorboard window size in jupyter

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, tensorboard

I want to get a full-size `TensorBoard` window when I use it in `jupyter` notebook.  I've tried this:

```
%load_ext tensorboard
# tf model built and fitted with TensorBoard callback
from tensorboard import notebook
%tensorboard --logdir log
notebook.display(port = 6006, height = 1000)
```

But I still only get the default half-size window.  If I make two cells:

```
%tensorboard --logdir log
## next cell
notebook.display(port = 6006, height = 1000)
```

I get  the half-size window below the first cell, and the full-size window below the second cell, but no way to get rid of the now redundant half-size window.

I'm sure there's some way to do this, but I can't find any example code that does it.

Comment: After using `notebook.display(port=6006, height=1000)`, I could see full size window. Can you confirm still you are facing half-size window. Thanks!